# After activity reload a button gets clicked on it's own?

Tags: java, android

Technically, my activity is not realoded, I only reload set of terms in buttons's setText. I will post my complete game class cause I don't know where is my mistake. I have a game activity, with 16 buttons, which are populated with random terms from db. After 45 seconds in the same xml layout I call nextQuestion method and load new 16 terms. My problem is...after first set of terms in my buttons, just after loading new set, one random button is clicked automatically. I don't know why and how. Same happens on the next loaded set of terms. Can someone find where is the problem?

I have two sets of buttons, 2 left and 2 right. I count 16 clicks then load next set of terms. Then disable the clicked buttons, and I again enable them in nextQuestion method.

```
public class Spojnice extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

        private int brojacIgara = 0;
        private int counter = 0;

        MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(35000, 1000);

    // labelForButton and tagForButton
       class MyStruct {
       public MyStruct (String lab, String t){
        label = lab;
        tag = t;
    }
       private String label;
       private String tag;
       }

       final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;
            private int brojacKlikova = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                brojacKlikova++;
                if (brojacKlikova < 16) {

                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFCC99));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        counter = counter + 5;
                        score.setText("Poeni: " + counter);
                    } else {
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));
                        button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    }
                    buttonClicked = null;
                }
                }else{
                brojacKlikova = 0;
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
         }
            }
     };


    LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private TextView pitanje, score, vreme;

    Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,izlaz;
    MediaPlayer buttonBack;
    public boolean music;

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
            brojacVremena.start();
        }
     };
    Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            finish();
         }
      };
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

        Typeface pitanjeType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myriad.ttf");
        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        buttonBack = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button31);
        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB8);
        izlaz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlaz);
        izlaz.setTypeface(dugmad);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPoeni);
        score.setTypeface(dugmad);
        vreme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVreme);
        vreme.setTypeface(dugmad);
        pitanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);
        pitanje.setTypeface(pitanjeType);

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        music = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);

        nextQuestion();
        brojacVremena.start(); 

        }

        public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,500);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

        }

    public void nextQuestion() {

        brojacIgara = brojacIgara + 1;


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{  

            mDbHelper.open(); 

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); 
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            if (brojacIgara < 4){

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a1.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a3.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b3.setEnabled(true);
            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3).label);
            a4.setTag(labelsA.get(3).tag);
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a4.setEnabled(true);
            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3).label);
            b4.setTag(labelsB.get(3).tag);
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b4.setEnabled(true);
            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4).label);
            a5.setTag(labelsA.get(4).tag);
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a5.setEnabled(true);
            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4).label);
            b5.setTag(labelsB.get(4).tag);
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b5.setEnabled(true);
            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5).label);
            a6.setTag(labelsA.get(5).tag);
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a6.setEnabled(true);
            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5).label);
            b6.setTag(labelsB.get(5).tag);
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b6.setEnabled(true);
            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6).label);
            a7.setTag(labelsA.get(6).tag);
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a7.setEnabled(true);
            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6).label);
            b7.setTag(labelsB.get(6).tag);
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b7.setEnabled(true);
            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7).label);
            a8.setTag(labelsA.get(7).tag);
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a8.setEnabled(true);
            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7).label);
            b8.setTag(labelsB.get(7).tag);
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b8.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Rezultat.class);
                i.putExtra("noviRezultat", counter);
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,4000);
                SwarmLeaderboard.submitScore(7427, counter);
            }

        }


        finally{
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
        izlaz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(music == true){
                    buttonBack.start();
                        }
                finish();   
            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        brojacVremena.cancel();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try to filter the code to exactly what's relevant? otherwise it's hard to parse it all.

Comment: I tried to check all of it, but I don't know where is my error. That's why I posted the entire code, maybe it's some small thing I missed. The main thing happens in the beggining in onClickListener. Also in nextQuestion method.